# Infinitely Powerful Computer

Tags: computer-science

What is the largest number a 4 bit CPU with two sets of registers can calculate?

Is it possible to create a processor that can continue to calculate infinitely? Has anybody heard anything like this because I cant find anything.

Comment: Arithmetic doesn't have to be performed entirely in registers as unitary operations. In the same way that people can perform long multiplication, long division, extended addition or subtraction, so can computers. Most languages have a library (sometimes more than one) that will calculate to arbitrary precision, i.e. as big or small as you like. The effective size limit is the memory available.

Comment: But can the CPU described above calculate with complete accuracy 43019221+12034657 ?

Answer (score 0):

4 Bit means the largest number it can calculate at one point in time is 2^4, or 16. Having said that, by breaking down the numbers and performing calculations on the numbers it is still possible to work with much larger numbers. It just becomes a matter of moving the values in and out of the registers, and the overhead that introduces.

I have no idea what your asking about calculating infinitely. Given finite memory, any computation on any computer , will eventually hit an out of memory point if continually calculating on a given set of problems. So, no.

Comment: By infinite i mean if the 4 bit computer had to add 100 + 100 and it only had four bits of memory when it reached the memory limit couldn't it just overwrite the first couple of bits? I mean it does not need them to continue calculating does it?

Comment: It would if you wanted an answer. Let's say you broke 100+100 into smaller pieces , you could calculate the individual pieces, but with out intermediate storage you could never reassemble the result and come up with the answer. So I'd you wanted it to just waste electricity, sure. Otherwise no.